# Using a 2D array as an argument in recursive function

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to recursively call a function with a 2d array as an argument.

My compile error is

> knapsack.cpp:76:55: error: cannot convert ‘int
>   (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)(knapsack_capacity + 1)) + -1)) + 1)]’ to
>   ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void backtrack(int**, int, int,
>   std::vector)’
>         backtrack(T, items_amount, knapsack_capacity, weights);

My function is declared like this:

```
void backtrack (int **T, int item, int weight, vector<int> weights)
{
        if (T[item][weight] == T[item-1][weight]) {
                cout << item << ", ";
                backtrack(T, item-1, weight-weights[item-1], weights);
        }
        else if (item <= 0 && weight <= 0) {
                // Dont do anything
        }
        else {
                backtrack(T, item-1, weight, weights);
        }
}
```

And being called like this:

```
backtrack(T, items_amount, knapsack_capacity, weights);
```

I looked in a million different ways of combining `[]` and `*`, but no success.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably passing an array, like `int arr[10][20];` to your function. Such an array does not decay to `int**`, but to `int (*)[20]` (i.e., pointer to array-of-20-int) . So, either change your function signature so that you specify the second dimension, or, instead of passing an array `int[10][20]`, pass a pointer-to-pointer `int**` (for which you have to allocate memory etc). Example of using both approaches:

```
#include <cstddef>

void f(int (*arr)[20]){}
void g(int**){}

int main()
{
    // using a pointer to array-of-20-ints
    int arr[10][20];
    f(arr);

    // 10 x 20 dynamic array, allocate
    int** ptr = new int*[10]; // allocate memory for the pointers to rows
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ptr[i] = new int[20]; // allocate each row

    // process
    g(ptr);

    // deallocate
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        delete[] ptr[i]; // delete each row
    delete[] ptr; // delete the memory allocated for the pointers to the rows
}
```

But, really, you should use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.